# Creating a XML file from a SQL database using Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, xml

There seems to be no information on this anywhere.

In anycase, I've been asked to create a Java program that takes information from a SQL database and creates a XML file.

I can see I'm going to be using the `DocumentBuilder` tool. However, I'm not sure exactly how to implement or how to begin, considering it's SQL.

The Database has not been created yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question?  You don't have a source database and you didn't list what you tried (which would add context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JAXB concepts to create xml from java and SQL.

This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) will be helpful for a start.

Comment: According to that link, I would just need to put the table values from the SQL database into a variable in Java, then put it into (Using the link you provided as an example) `customer.setId(variable);`?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using StAX because it's faster than DOM and you know exactly what is going to the XML.

Here is the [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipstx4/) to a tutorial.

Comment: Okay, so I took that code, and tried to run it to see what the output was compared to the java code, however it gave me an exception at `javax.xml.stream.isPrefixDefaultingis not supported`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your main purpose? If you're trying to learn JDBC or XML APIs, or this is your application biz logic, the answers provided by Rion are good for start.

But if you're trying just to fetch some data from DB and convert them to XML, I think [Data Benerator](http://databene.org/databene-benerator) framework is good for you. It has been designed for database and load testing, but could be useful for you too.